# Permutation graph and the number of inversion statistics

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, intuition

Let $K_m$ be the number of m-cliques, $m \in N$, in a random permutation graph $G_n$ with $n$ vertices and $\pi_n$ is the corresponding permutation representation in $S_n$.
I am looking for a basic explanation of the facts:

1. $K_1=n$ and $K_2$ is the number of edges in $G_n$ is the number of inversions in $\pi_n$ (denoted by $Inv(\pi_n)$). Why so?
2. Why the permutation statistic $Inv(\pi_n)$ satisfies the central limit theorem
   $$ \left| P\left( \frac{\mathrm{Inv}(\pi)-\frac 12{n\choose 2}}{\sqrt{n(n-1)(2n+5)/72}}\leq x\right)-\Phi(x)\right| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}, $$
   where $\Phi(x)$ denotes the standard normal distribution.

Any basic explanations on that topics are highly welcomed.

Reference: [A study on random permutation graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.06678.pdf), part 2, page 4.

Comment: The link is broken. You should explain the construction of the graph either way.

Comment: I corrected the link, thank you

Comment: The first question is a matter of understanding that a $1-$clique is a vertex and there are $n$ of them and the $2-clique$ is an edge and by construction there are $Inv(\pi _n).$ Now, the second question is quite more complicated to know what you need. Consider $X_i = \text{# j<i s.t }\pi _n(i)<\pi _n(j)$ hence $Inv(\pi _n)=\sum X_i$ and then compute the expected value and variance. Use Stein method because these $X_i$ are not independent.

Comment: @Phicar Thank you. Could you clarify the Stein method for the particular case please?